How to use the LORA based weights for the evaluation/inference?
tuned the Qwen-Vl model using LoRA, and I have the saved checkpoints like the following:

However, I do not know how to load the Lora weights and then do the inference based on the models's updated weights with LoRA. I saw this answer, where for example,
import torch
from peft import PeftModel    
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, LlamaTokenizer, StoppingCriteria, StoppingCriteriaList, TextIteratorStreamer

model_name = "decapoda-research/llama-7b-hf"
adapters_name = "lucas0/empath-llama-7b"

print(f"Starting to load the model {model_name} into memory")

m = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_name,
    #load_in_4bit=True,
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
    device_map={"": 0}
)
m = PeftModel.from_pretrained(m, adapters_name)
m = m.merge_and_unload()
tok = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

In my case
model_name = "Qwen/Qwen-VL"

what should be the adaptor setting and how to update the model weights with lora weights (which has been saved locally)?
Is the following correct?
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
            "Qwen/Qwen-VL", device_map='cuda', trust_remote_code=True)
# Load the adapter weights
adapter_weights_path = "/path/to/checkpoint-5000/adapter_model.bin"
adapter_weights = torch.load(adapter_weights_path)

# Load the adapter weights into the model (assuming the adapter matches)
model.load_state_dict(adapter_weights, strict=False)

# Ensure the model is in evaluation mode
model.eval()


What code you used to save your model?

@حمزةنبيل this code
https://github.com/QwenLM/Qwen-VL/blob/master/finetune.py
and also this is the command https://github.com/QwenLM/Qwen-VL/blob/master/finetune/finetune_lora_ds.sh

This question is similar to: I want to merge my PEFT adapter model with the base model and make a fully new model. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
